# lexical scoping example not working

Tags: javascript, closures, lexical-scope, lexical-closures

Why would this closure not work?

```
  var derivedKey;
  lightwallet.keystore.deriveKeyFromPassword(password, function (err, pwDerivedKey) {
    derivedKey = pwDerivedKey;
  });

  if (!derivedKey){
    console.error ("ERROR no derivedKey");
  }
```

Thows the Error. What are possible explanations for this?

Comment: is (the deprecated) `lightwallet.keystore.deriveKeyFromPassword` asynchronous? that's why

Comment: Bingo! That was obvious!